# log(n) complexity. Difficulty understanding example

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

So, I am revisiting complexity analysis.

Here's the example: the instructor reduced an algorithm to:

n*(1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n), and I can't seem to grasp why the part in parentheses is log(n).

Comment: All he said was "this is the definition of log(n)".

Comment: @R.V. That's unfortunate because it is most definitely _not_ the definition of $\log n$. (In particular, as $n\to\infty$ it tends to $\gamma + \log n$ for some constant $\gamma\approx 0.577$.)

Comment: Most of the answers why `log(n)` is in there, but the important part, from a time complexity point of view, is that the (Euler-Mascheroni) constant part is NOT included because it does not change as the input changes.  Hence its `O(log(n))`, without the constant.

Comment: Please disprove your instructor's claim by showing that $1/1 \ne \ln(1)$, and for good measure $1/1+1/2 \ne \ln(2)$.

Answer (score 20):

Do you know the [Harmonic series (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics))?

$$1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} = 1 + \sum_{i=2}^{n} \frac{1}{i} \le 1 + \int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{x} \text{d}x = 1 + \ln n = \Theta(\log n).$$

Similarly, we also have 
$$1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i} \ge \int_{1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{x} \text{d}x = \ln (n+1) = \Theta(\log n).$$

---

The formula above follows from

$$\int_{a}^{b+1} f(x) \text{d}x \le \sum_{i=a}^{b} f(i) \le \int_{a-1}^{b} f(x) \text{d}x$$

when $f(x)$ is non-increasing.

Answer (score 8):

$1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{n}= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i}=H_n$ where $H_n$ is the $n^{th}$ harmonic number.

So inside the parenthesis you don't have $\log(n)$.

But, what can be proved is that:

- $\ln(n+1) < H_n \le 1 + \ln(n)$
- $H_{n+1} - \ln(n+1) < H_n - \ln(n)$

so that the $H_n - \ln(n) \ge 0$ and the difference **decreases**.

**Example**:

\begin{align*}
H_1 - \ln(1) &=  1\\
H_2 - \ln(2) &=  0.80...\\
H_3 - \ln(3) &=  0.73...\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
H_{10} - \ln(10) &=  0.62..\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
H_{100} - \ln(100) &=  0.58...
\end{align*}

The limit tends to a constant called the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html)
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (H_n - \ln(n))=0.577...$$

So, to conclude, $H_n = \Theta(\log  n)$.

Answer (score 1):

"All he said was 'this is the definition of $\log n$'". That's sad. Because it's wrong, and because your instructor should be helping you, and this isn't helpful.

If your maths isn't very strong, here's a simpler method to see what's going on:

You have a sum $1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + \dots + 1/n$. That's one term $= 1$, one term $= 1/2$. Then two terms $1/3$ and $1/4$, both $\geq 1/4$, so their total is $\geq 1/2$. Then four terms $1/5$, $1/6$, $1/7$, $1/8$, all four $\geq 1/8$, so their total is $\geq 1/2$. Then eight terms up to $1/16$ add up with a total $\geq 1/2$, and so on. If you do the sum up to $n = 2^k$ then you added the number $1$, and $k$ times the number $1/2$. The sum is $\geq 1 + k/2$.

On the other hand, $1/3$ and $1/4$ are $\leq 1/2$ so they add to a total $\leq1$. $1/5$ to $1/8$ are each $\leq 1/4$, so they add to a total $\leq 1$. The terms $1/9$ to $1/16$ are $\leq 1/8$, so their total is $\leq 1$. If you sum everything up to $n = 2^k$, the total sum is $\leq 1/2 + k$.

So the sum up to $n = 2^k$ is between $1 + k/2$ and $1/2 + k$, or between $1 + (\log_2 n) / 2$ and $1/2 + \log_2 n$, which is $\Theta (\log n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Stolz-Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem):

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1 + 1/2 + \cdots + 1/n}{\log n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1/(n + 1)}{\log(n + 1) - \log n} =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1/(n + 1)}{\log(1 + 1/n)} =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1/(n + 1)}{1/n} = 1,
$$
so $H_n = \Theta(\log n)$.

Answer (score 0):

The important part to understand is that the time complexity of an algorithm (when expressed using big O notation) **excludes coefficients and lower order terms**.

Other answers have shown where the `log(n)` term comes from, but your instructor is absolutely correct to leave out the constant part of the expression when stating the time complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: This is true but I suspect the asker's actual difficulty was in seeing the connection between the harmonic series and logarithms and probably isn't related to the disappearing constant.